# Does the language used in schema need to match the HTML lang attribute?

Tags: internationalization, schema, json-ld

I have a multi-language site. Each language has its own language specific url with the HTML lang attribute set to match the language the content is written in.

Do I need to use schema that matches the HTML lang attribute?

For example, if the pages lang attribute is set to `ru` and the content is written in Russian, but the schema is written in English, will a search bot care o?

Comment: Does each language have its own unique URLs? Do you detect a user's language and change content or redirect based on that?